# How to call object id on recently created user

Tags: user-input, objectid, back4app

Lets just say I created a new user using this code

```
 void Signup() async {
    final parseUser = ParseUser.createUser(_nama,_password,_email);
    await parseUser.signUp();}
```

and I want to take the ObjectId from that created user immediately (as I need to create other back4app class based on that objectId)

How do you make the codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseUser.id` to retrieve the object id of this user object right after it was saved.

Comment: cant use parseUser.id, it is just appear as ParseUser.ObjectId (flutter) and yes I already try this, and it came up still NULL, it seems even after I save it, it is only make save ONLINE and that data cant be mine yet

Comment: Yes I have tried on that. Still dont generate the proper objectId

Comment: That's strange. The object id should be available after awaiting the sign up function to complete. Would you mind to share more details on how you are verifying the object id? Are you logging it right after `await parseUser.signUp();`? Would you mind to share the code?

Comment: from my experience it cannot be SIMULTANEOUS action. (getting the user objectId) . so I had to sign up, and later if I want to add more details to User class, it can be done later. so.. since people are bit late to answer this, I continue my project using different method to access that objectId.. which is after SIGNUP that is :p